# How do I create a Step Graph in Excel?

Tags: excel, charts

Suppose I have a set of values: <0-4.5, 1>, <4.6-9.3, 2>, <9.4-12.2, 3> and I want to display a simple, three step graph. One step would span from zero to 4.5 and the height should be 1, the second step from 4.6 to 9.3 and the height would be 2 and so on.

How do I do it in Excel?

Edit: A hack would be to generate pairs: <0,1>, <0.1,1>...<4.4,1>, <4.5,1> and use a scatter graph. But, really!

Comment: In addition to @Tom Sharpe 's excellent solution: Don't leave blank rows inside segments, and don't have segments of length 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure exactly how you want the graph to look, but another workaround is to select a scatter joined by lines. If you want a gap anywhere, put in a missing value:

```
+------+---+
|  x   | y |
+------+---+
|    0 | 0 |
|    0 | 1 |
|  4.5 | 1 |
|  4.5 | 0 |
|      |   |
|  4.6 | 0 |
|  4.6 | 2 |
|  9.3 | 2 |
|  9.3 | 0 |
|      |   |
|  9.4 | 0 |
|  9.4 | 3 |
| 12.2 | 3 |
| 12.2 | 0 |
+------+---+
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Use the following data set:

```
| x    | y |
|------|---|
| 0.1  | 1 |
| 0.2  | 1 |
| 0.3  | 1 |
| 0.4  | 1 |
| 0.5  | 1 |
| 0.6  | 1 |
| 0.7  | 1 |
| 0.8  | 1 |
| 0.9  | 1 |
| 1    | 1 |
| 1.1  | 1 |
| 1.2  | 1 |
| 1.3  | 1 |
| 1.4  | 1 |
| 1.5  | 1 |
| 1.6  | 1 |
| 1.7  | 1 |
| 1.8  | 1 |
| 1.9  | 1 |
| 2    | 1 |
| 2.1  | 1 |
| 2.2  | 1 |
| 2.3  | 1 |
| 2.4  | 1 |
| 2.5  | 1 |
| 2.6  | 1 |
| 2.7  | 1 |
| 2.8  | 1 |
| 2.9  | 1 |
| 3    | 1 |
| 3.1  | 1 |
| 3.2  | 1 |
| 3.3  | 1 |
| 3.4  | 1 |
| 3.5  | 1 |
| 3.6  | 1 |
| 3.7  | 1 |
| 3.8  | 1 |
| 3.9  | 1 |
| 4    | 1 |
| 4.1  | 1 |
| 4.2  | 1 |
| 4.3  | 1 |
| 4.4  | 1 |
| 4.5  | 1 |
| 4.6  | 2 |
| 4.7  | 2 |
| 4.8  | 2 |
| 4.9  | 2 |
| 5    | 2 |
| 5.1  | 2 |
| 5.2  | 2 |
| 5.3  | 2 |
| 5.4  | 2 |
| 5.5  | 2 |
| 5.6  | 2 |
| 5.7  | 2 |
| 5.8  | 2 |
| 5.9  | 2 |
| 6    | 2 |
| 6.1  | 2 |
| 6.2  | 2 |
| 6.3  | 2 |
| 6.4  | 2 |
| 6.5  | 2 |
| 6.6  | 2 |
| 6.7  | 2 |
| 6.8  | 2 |
| 6.9  | 2 |
| 7    | 2 |
| 7.1  | 2 |
| 7.2  | 2 |
| 7.3  | 2 |
| 7.4  | 2 |
| 7.5  | 2 |
| 7.6  | 2 |
| 7.7  | 2 |
| 7.8  | 2 |
| 7.9  | 2 |
| 8    | 2 |
| 8.1  | 2 |
| 8.2  | 2 |
| 8.3  | 2 |
| 8.4  | 2 |
| 8.5  | 2 |
| 8.6  | 2 |
| 8.7  | 2 |
| 8.8  | 2 |
| 8.9  | 2 |
| 9    | 2 |
| 9.1  | 2 |
| 9.2  | 2 |
| 9.3  | 2 |
| 9.4  | 3 |
| 9.5  | 3 |
| 9.6  | 3 |
| 9.7  | 3 |
| 9.8  | 3 |
| 9.9  | 3 |
| 10   | 3 |
| 10.1 | 3 |
| 10.2 | 3 |
| 10.3 | 3 |
| 10.4 | 3 |
| 10.5 | 3 |
| 10.6 | 3 |
| 10.7 | 3 |
| 10.8 | 3 |
| 10.9 | 3 |
| 11   | 3 |
| 11.1 | 3 |
| 11.2 | 3 |
| 11.3 | 3 |
| 11.4 | 3 |
| 11.5 | 3 |
| 11.6 | 3 |
| 11.7 | 3 |
| 11.8 | 3 |
| 11.9 | 3 |
| 12   | 3 |
| 12.1 | 3 |
```

Highlight the data set, and insert a chart using `Recommended Charts` and pick the one you prefer as shown below.

[image: Sample]

It can be a bar chart or line chart not necessarily a scatter chart, but the preparation is similar. Charting is not that intuitive in excel and needs a lot of workarounds sometimes.

Cheers :)